# xpath - text()[index] usage

Tags: html, xml, dom, xpath

What's the purpose & usage of using the `text()` with an index like this: `text()[index]`?

I have observed that `//p/text[2]` gets me only `paragraph text` in this example:

```
<p>
    <strong>important text</strong>
    paragraph text
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `p` element node has three child nodes:

1. a `text` node with white space
2. the `strong` element node
3. a `text` node with white space followed by `paragraph text` followed by white space

If you use `//p/text()`, you select all `text` child nodes, using `//p/text()[2]` you select the second `text` child node (which is the third child node considering all kind of nodes).

Comment: My bad, I forget that whitespace before `strong` is counted as a text node. From your response I understand that `text()` can be fragmented (divided), when other `tags (like strong or b)` exist between text.

Comment: @h4k1m, an element can have mixed content where text is mixed with element children. A single text node is not fragmented or divided. `//p/text()` selects several text nodes (two in the sample), as much as `//p/*` selects all child elements (there is only one in the sample but if there were more it would select several).